# Similar and congruent triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $h_a,h_b,h_c$ the length of the heights.

(a) Find similar triangles at which it holds that $ah_a=bh_b$.

(b) Use (a) to show : Is $A'B'C'$ a second triangle and $h_a,h_b,h_c$ are again the length of the heights of this triangle, so these triangles are congruent.

$$$$

For (a) do we have to give two specific triangles, i.e. give the negth of the sides? Or what exactly is asked?

Comment: I don't get (a).  The area of the triangle is always 1/2 times height time side length.  This quantity is independent of the side chosen.

Answer (score 0):

For part (a), yes, we have to find two similar triangles for which $ah_a=bh_b$ holds.

Draw $h_a$ and $h_b$ inside $\triangle ABC$. $h_a \cap BC \in D$. $h_b \cap CA \in E$. With simple angle chasing, $$\triangle ADC \sim \triangle BEC$$

Comment: These aresimilar because they have three angles equal, right? Angle at $C$ is common, so equal. The angles at $E$ and at $D$ are both right angles and so equal. Since they have two equal angles the third one is also equal. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct.

Comment: At (b) we have two triangles with equal lengths of heights and we want to show that the two triangles are congruent, right?

Comment: Yes that seems right. But, is $A'B'C'$ given similar to $ABC$ ?

Comment: As far I understand that, we have a triangle $A'B'C'$ which has $h_a, h_b, h_c$ as in the triangle $ABC$. So do we have to show first that $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ are similar?

Comment: @MaryStar Indeed, we must show second triangle has same angles and proportional sides for them to be congruent. I'm not sure if this results holds, that given three altitudes, a unique triangle exists. I'd like to see others' take on this too.

Comment: At the statement we have taht "Use (a).." so we have that $\frac{h_a}{h_b}=\frac{b}{a}$ and so we get also that $\frac{h_a}{h_b}=\frac{b'}{a'}$ and so we get $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{b'}{a'}$, or cannot we not just take the equality of (a) ?

Comment: I see. One similarity is not enough. For example, $3,4,5$ and $3,4,6$ triangles are not similar. However taking pairwise altitudes, we do get that $a/a'=b/b'=c/c'$ from which it follows. Nice question!

Comment: So we take the equation of question (a) for all pairs of sides?

Comment: Yes, you're right. @MaryStar

Comment: So since the sides of each triangle are proportional we get that the two triangles are congruent?

Comment: In addition to sides being proportional, heights are equal, so $ADC \cong A'D'C'$ etc.

Comment: Ah.. so each pair of smaller triangles are congruent and so the two bigger triangles must also be congruent, right?

Comment: Yes you got it.

Comment: Could you explain tome how it follows that $ADC \cong A'D'C'$ knowing that the sides of each triangle are proportional the heights are equal?